# Can PouchDB be pre-populated?

Tags: local-storage, indexeddb, pouchdb

I don't want to populate a browser's PouchDB (IndexedDB) on the first visit to my Web  site. I want to send a pre-created PouchDB file that gets loaded by the browser and saved into local  storage. Is that possible? Otherwise, I'll have to send a script that creates hundreds  of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a couchdb/pouchdb dump file using:

https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-dump-cli

Then when you page loads, you check if your database has any data, if not, then download the dump file and load it using pouchdb-load:

https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-load